# Subspaces of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ which contains a nontrivial weak* closed subalgebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, banach-spaces

Let $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ denotes the Banach space of bounded holomorphic functions in the unit disc. Consider the weak* topology on $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$
that it inherits as the dual of $L^{1}(\mathbb{T}).$ Under this topology $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ is a weak* closed subspace of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}).$ I have the following question:

Does there exist a subspace $M\subseteq H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ which is not weak* closed and contains a nontrivial weak* closed unital subalgebra of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})?$

By nontrivial I mean it contains a nonconstant holomorphic function.

Comment: The even functions $f(z)=g(z^2)$ look weak $*$ closed, and then just take a suitable $M$ that contains these.

Comment: yes, it is weak* closed. But I'm not able to see how to choose $M?$ For example disc algebra $A(\mathbb{D})$ is not weak* closed but it also does not contain the weak* algebra generated by $z^2.$

Comment: Well, just take an $M\supseteq A$, with $A$ even functions, that is not weak $*$ closed (for example, not norm closed would work).

Answer (score -1):

I discussed with some of my friends and found this example. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the set of all polynomials, and let $\mathcal{U}:=\{\varphi(z^2):\varphi\in H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})\}.$ Set $$M=\mathcal{P}+\mathcal{U}.$$ Note that $M$ contains $\mathcal{U}$ which is weak* closed. 
Then as the weak* closure of polynomials is dense in $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D}),$ the weak* closure of $M$ is $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D}).$ But $M$ is not $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D}).$ To see that note $\sin{z}\in H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ but $\sin{z}$ can not be written as a sum of a polynomial and an even function in $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D}).$

Comment: This is essentially the same idea that @ChristianRemling suggested in his comment above